# Possible to animate grid-area property?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-grid, dom-events

I have an overlay element for 2 buttons and I'm trying to implement a sort of active state by changing the grid-area property of the element to match that of the button that has been clicked.

I was wondering if it's possible to animate this change and have some sort of slide animation.

```js
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
const hello = document.querySelector('.btn-1');
const world = document.querySelector('.btn-2');

hello.addEventListener('click', e => {
  overlay.style.gridArea = '1 / 1 / -1 / 2';
});

world.addEventListener('click', e => {
  overlay.style.gridArea = '1 / 2 / -1 / -1';
});
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 1000px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr / repeat(2, min-content);
}

.overlay {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / -1 / 2;
}

.btn {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / -1 / 2;
}

.btn-2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <span class="btn btn-1">Hello</span>
  <span class="btn btn-2">World</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a nice library that can accomplish just that very easily. I'm not able to include the cdn link in the snippet for some reason but the project is called [animate-css-grid](https://github.com/aholachek/animate-css-grid) on github.

```js
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
const hello = document.querySelector('.btn-1');
const world = document.querySelector('.btn-2');
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');

animateCSSGrid.wrapGrid(grid, {duration : 600});
hello.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (overlay.classList.contains('overlay--2')) {
    overlay.classList.remove('overlay--2');
  }
});

world.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (!overlay.classList.contains('overlay--2')) {
    overlay.classList.add('overlay--2');
  }
});
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr / repeat(2, min-content);
}

.overlay {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / -1 / 2;
  z-index: -1;
}

.overlay--2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / -1 / -1;
}

.btn {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / -1 / 2;
}

.btn-2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <span class="btn btn-1">Hello</span>
  <span class="btn btn-2">World</span>
</div>
```